# select statement where username is equal to session

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

simple question, is it possible to do this? Select Id from Table where username = Session?

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select ID from CustomerDetails Where CustomerName ="Session["New"], con); - this has been solved.
```

2nd question:

i want to implement it like this:

```
if (Session["New"] != reader["ID"].ToString())
            {
                Response.Redirect("NotAuthorized.aspx");
            }
```

giving me an error in my if statement. any tricks?

Full code is here:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        string str = "select ID from CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '"+Session["New"].ToString()+"'";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["New"] != reader["ID"].ToString())
            {
                Response.Redirect("NotAuthorized.aspx");
            }
```

Comment: you want only fetch the data on label?

Comment: yes @ash060 how do i do that?

Comment: try which code i had share .

Comment: you can try like this :SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select ID from CustomerDetails Where CustomerName='"+Convert.ToString(Session["New"])+"'"), con);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select ID from CustomerDetails Where CustomerName ='"+Session["New"].ToString()+"'", con);
string ID =cm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Assuming,

Session["New"] contains username (datatype as string)

Comment: thanks a lot. kindly view my 2nd question. please and thanks

Comment: the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable , property or indexer

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod you must open the reader before use it .
try  
 `SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114026/discussion-between-manu-varghese-and-paolo-duhaylungsod).

Comment: sir? im in the discussion chat

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID from CustomerDetails ", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.fill(dt);
int count=dt.Rows.Count;
if (Count > 0)
{
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
Label2.Text =dt1.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more error proof I think it is better to use named parameters in your SQL command like this:

```
// suppose customer ID is an integer
int customerId = 0;
string customerName = (string)Session["New"];
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM CustomerDetails WHERE CustomerName = @customerName", sqlCon);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", customerName);
    object result = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result != null)
        customerId = (int)result;
}
```